# Does TOML support top level arrays of dictionaries?

Tags: toml

I am trying to write a configuration file that would be an array (list) or dictionaries (hashes, tables). In JSON terms that would be for instance

```json
[
   {
      "a":1,
      "b":2
   },
   {
      "a":10,
      "b":20
   }
]
```

I was hoping that

```ini
[[]]
a = 1
b = 2

[[]]
a = 10
b = 20
```

would be correct, but it is rejected by my Go parser with

```
 unexpected token "]]", was expecting a table array key
```

This suggests that only top-level dictionaries (hashes, tables) are allowed. Is that really the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TOML 1.0.0 does not permit a top level array.

From [github.com/toml-lang/toml](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/#comparison-with-other-formats):

> TOML always has a hash table at the top level of the file, which can easily have data nested inside its keys, but it doesn't permit top-level arrays or floats, so it cannot directly serialize some data.